# Click Cancel button in JXColorSelectionButton

Tags: java, swingx, cancel-button

In my java application i load a JXColorSelectionButton from [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/) to choose a color from it then click "Ok" to apply the color. After doing this if i click the JXColorSelectionButton once again but click "Cancel" the color is reset.

This is a wrong behavior as when clicking "Cancel" the first color i chose should remain the same. The main problem is that there is no way i can detect if "Ok" or "Cancel" is clicked in the JXColorSelectionButton's dialog to prevent this behavior.

**Anyone can tell me a solution for this ?**

Comment: hmm .. not entirely sure if that's a bug or a feature (personally, would tend to the former) but certainly worth a deeper debate. Would suggest you file a report in the swingx issue tracker and start a discussion in the swingx forum. Thanks!

Comment: @kleopatra: I see it is a normal behavior, and not a feature !

Comment: Just a note for anyone who reads this, i have issued this in SwingX Jira bug reporting, and it seems to be fixed in SwingX v1.6.3: http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1454